# How to add fontawesome fonts in css pseudo elements

Tags: css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I'm trying to add FontAwesome icons to css pseudo elements

If I add the icon using html in the regular way it does work, but I'm trying to add the fonts to a bootstrap accordion so the icon changes in the collapsed state. That part works, but the icon is not showing. Instead there is a empty square in chrome and a square with the hex code in firefox.

Added kit (tried before and after css is loaded):

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/30fc0982d8.js"></script>
```

CSS code:

```css
#faq a:after{
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    content: '\f107';

}

#faq a.collapsed:after{
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    content: '\f106';
}
```

I would expect the icon to just show, but it doesn't. Any thoughts?

Edit: Forgot to add, I did some extensive searching on this and found several posts. Typically the solution was to add `font-weight: 900`, but as you can see I already did that.
Edit2: This question was marked duplicate but for FontAwesome with JS+SVG. I'm using the webfonts option.

Comment: PLease refer this URL:    https://jsfiddle.net/jignashagpatel/4yzu16m2/8/

Answer (score 0):

as per the comment u need font awesome 5 this is the new code.

```
<style>
#faq a:after{
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f078";

}
#faq a.collapsed:after{
  content: "\f077";
}
</style>
<section id="faq">
  <a></a>
  <a class="collapsed"></a>
</section>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/30fc0982d8.js""></script>
```

Comment: OP wants to use Font Awesome 5, not 4.7.

Comment: I just edit this code as per your Comment Just try it once. It works...

Comment: @KuldipKoradia, you are correct with your solution, but not the reason. Someone else posted the link to a bug, it was by mistake added tot the pro sextion. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

change the `font-family` name as below

```
   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
```

```css
#faq a:after {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-weight: 900;
  content: '\f107';
}

#faq a.collapsed:after {
  content: '\f106';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/30fc0982d8.js"></script>

<div id="faq">
  <a class=""> link</a>
  <br>

  <a class="collapsed"> collapsed link</a>

</div>
```

Comment: What suprises me is that f107 is available in free's [cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet).

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek I've edited my answer and please refer to this issue https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/15137

Comment: @Soothran, you're correct. This is a bug and changing the free to pro fixed it.